# how to define a tag for tracking video play in google tag manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

in one of our site pages we have an embedded video (from a local site in iran called Aparat-something like Youtube). how should I define trigger and tag for tracking this video in google tag manager?

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in trigger and variables for tracking youtube videos.

Check the ones you want, I'm only going to use the "Video status" as an example:
[image]

Create a new Youtube video trigger, this one will track starts and completes:
[image]

Then create a GA event tag to track this and set the trigger to the video trigger created above:
[image]